# How to config cron value of @Scheduled in application.properties

Tags: spring, cron, schedule

I am using spring-schedule like this.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Autowired
    private ISomeJob someJob;

    /**
     * do a Job every 5 minutes.
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * ?")
    public void foo(){
        someJob.doSomething();
    }
}
```

It worked. But there is a problem.
I have two profiles named `debug` and `release`.
I want do this job every 5 minutes in `debug` but per hour in `release`.
So is there any way to config the value of `cron` in application.properties.

Comment: Can't you add an expression `@Scheduled(cron = "${some.profile.cron}")` to swap the cron?

Comment: @ StanislavL  I thought the expression can only be used in `@Value`. I just tried and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I have same problem as this question. Please help how do I change cron = ? in @Scheduled notation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add an expression `@Scheduled(cron = "${some.profile.cron}")` to swap the `cron` depending on selected profile.